# Unpermitted parameters error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to add a nested form in my app, but shell shows me an error:

```
Unpermitted parameter: description
```

there is my model

```
class Chart < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :descriptions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :descriptions
end
```

There is strong params in my controller:

```
  def chart_params
    params.require(:chart).permit(:title, descriptions_attributes: [:name])
  end
```

This is my form:

```
= form_for @chart do |f|
  = f.text_field :title
  = f.fields_for :descriptions do |d|
    = d.text_field :name
  = f.submit
```

What am I doing wrong?

***upd***

I was change form and action `new` in controller

form

```
 = form_for @chart do |f|
    = f.text_field :title
    = f.fields_for @descriptions do |d|
      = d.text_field :name
    = f.submit
```

action new

```
  def new
    @chart = Chart.new
    @descriptions = @chart.descriptions.build
  end
```

Comment: May sound silly, but try refreshing your browser. At a glance, it looks correct.

Comment: are you sure you have `params[:chart][:descriptions_attributes]` and not `params[:chart][:description]` when you submit the form?

Comment: @MrYoshiji yes, you right I get `params[:chart][:description]`. but why?

Comment: I don't know, `fields_for`'s behavior is weird sometimes, can't explain it... Try using `f.fields_for @chart.descriptions.build` ( I actually never use string or symbol for `form_for` or `fields_for` but I initialize the object and pass as argument instead, it works 99% of time)

Comment: I updated question, but I still get the same error

Comment: when you inspect your HTML output, the inputs' name of the `fields_for` are like `chart[description]`, right? It should be `chart[descriptions_attributes][]`. Try `f.fields_for @descriptions, as: :descriptions` to see if it changes the inputs' name

Comment: hmm, I added that, but html don't changes. I think, I do it all over again :D

Comment: @wweare did you try `f.fields_for :descriptions, @chart.descriptions.build` and don't initialize `@descriptions` in the `new` action.

Comment: @bnanua it work, make an answer and I note it tick.And why it work?Why the same don't work in controller action?

Answer (score 1):

The name attribute for the text_field 'name' should be 'chart[descriptions_attributes][name]'.

Please check the code snippet below:

```
= form_for @chart do |f|
  = f.text_field :title
  = f.fields_for :descriptions_attributes, @descriptions do |d|
    = d.text_field :name
  = f.submit
```

No changes required for the new action of controller.

Comment: thank you for the answer man, but now I didn't check your solution.I gave this app :(